# Jquery : Get all the inputs with onclick contains specific string jQuery 1.2.6

Tags: javascript, jquery, onclick, typeerror

We have radio buttons with

```
value = "lock" onclick="toggleLock(this, 1,"Unlocked");"
value = "lock" onclick="toggleLock(this, 2,"Unlocked");"
value = "unlock" onclick="toggleLock(this, 2,"Locked");"
value = "lock" onclick="toggleLock(this, 2,"Unlocked");"
value = "unlock" onclick="toggleLock(this, 2,"Unlocked");"
.
.
.
```

Now we need to select all inputs with onclick which are sending "Unlocked". So we have used code as

```
$('input[value="lock"][onclick$="\"Unlocked\");"]');
```

The above code giving error as 
jquery.js:1716 Uncaught TypeError: z.substr is not a function

We are having two other project with jQuery v1.9.0, we are not facing any issue in this version

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There may be a simple approach for it.

You can use [**data**](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.data/) attribute and add specific value to it.Hope the following snippet will help

For example

```
value = "lock" data-status = "Unlocked" onclick="toggleLock(this, 1,"Unlocked");"
value = "lock" data-status = "Unlocked" onclick="toggleLock(this, 2,"Unlocked");"
value = "unlock" onclick="toggleLock(this, 2,"Locked");"
value = "lock" data-status = "Unlocked"  onclick="toggleLock(this, 2,"Unlocked");"
value = "unlock" data-status = "Unlocked" onclick="toggleLock(this, 2,"Unlocked");"
```

Now you can use this `data` attribute to select the specific element you want

```
$('[data-status="Unlock"]')
```

Comment: @Falcon please consider upvotong & accepting it as answer